# An Invitation to Meta visitors to participate beyond reading posts

Tags: support, meta

Most Meta posts are visited 75-150 times. Those same Meta posts tend to accumulate (at a rough guess and on average) a total of 8-12 unique votes.

Meta works because you're willing to move your mouse to an arrow and click a button. I understand that you might not want to "stick your neck out" to voice an opinion or set a precedent — but that's actually what Meta is for. Our community modifies rules and makes clarifications because we, the proverbial people, are willing to cast what is for all intent and purposes is an *anonymous* vote.

Unfortunately, it appears somewhere around 93% of the people who visit Meta never bother to cast a vote.

*It's worth thinking about that. I'd have to go look at the stats to prove this, but my knee-jerk suspicion is that about 2% of the active users on Worldbuilding.SE visit Meta and, of those, only 8% participate. That means the policies of this Stack are being set by around 0.2% of its users.*

This is an invitation to participate beyond merely reading the Meta posts. Please, get in the habit of voting, writing answers, and posting questions. You can try this out right now. It won't matter if you...

- up-vote
- down-vote
- write a comment complaining that the post isn't relevant to Stack policy
- post an answer explaining how I'm completely up in the night
- or post a new question demanding to know why you should be expected to click your mouse button...

But doing so will show you're here for more than idle curiosity or simple entertainment. You'll be *participating!*

Comment: How many of those 93% are the same core users visiting more than once a day? Also, Meta is pretty quiet at the moment. The current batch of questions seem to be simmering without any new activity, so there's just not much to vote or comment on!

Comment: @elemtilas I'm jumping to the conclusion that SE's smart enough to count users only once. But, I could be wrong. Maybe those awful page counters from the 90s aren't as dead as I thought they were.

Comment: @JBH I tried out of curiosity a long time ago, it is once per registered user, but I think you can double up if you're not registered. I don't know how they handle the count with only IPs...

Comment: Also... [According to SE statistics, only a small percentage of people that have read meta-posts have actually answered and voted them, so if you end up liking these posts, consider voting and answering, it's free, and you can (almost) always change your mind. Enjoy the post.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szCUXq544is) .

Comment: 10% participation is pretty much normal in any environment, consistently getting anything over that is a considerable achievement

Comment: @Tortliena No, it's more than once even per registered user, but it doesn't count refreshes within 15 minutes or less. See [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/278659). So elemtilas is right, the same person visiting a post multiple times will increase the view counter.

Comment: @Separatrix We're not seeing 10%. We're seeing 0.2%.

Answer (score 5):

> "*Meta works because you're willing to move your mouse to an arrow and click a button.*"

Erm, no, it works because (and when) people discuss things.
Votes can suggest agreement or disagreement, and a lack of votes can indicate a lack of interest or a neutral stance. Votes alone won't change things.

Nevertheless, the point you're ultimately making, that more participation is necessary for a healthy site, is absolutely true.

And so from me in nuanced emphasis of points made no vote here but an answer.

Comment: Considering that my post asked that people up-vote, down-vote, comment, post and answer, or post a new question, I'm delighted to thank you for participating.